# Python conditional expression invalid syntax

Tags: python-3.x, list-comprehension

I want to use conditional list comprehension to return a "valid" list of switches. A valid switch is the following:
The first two letters represent the country, so `[CH]SW002`. These letters must match with the first two letters of the current device. If the device is a notebook, `US[NB]001`, the country prefix can be disregarded.

The devices below should therefore have the following switches assigned to them:

- CHPC001: CHSW002
- USPC001: USSW001, USSW002
- USNB001: USSW001, USSW002, CHSW002

Below is my code, but it raises a syntax error:

```
switches = ['USSW001', 'USSW002', 'CHSW002']
devices = ['CHPC001', 'USPC001', 'USNB001']

for device in devices:
    print([sw if 'nb' in device else sw if device[:2] in sw for sw in switches])
```

Comment: I didn't understand, what relations should be in the final result? How should they look?

Comment: You have two such expressions, and the second is missing an `else`. What should happen in the case where the test in `sw if device[:2] in sw` is `False`?

Comment: `print([sw if 'nb' in device else sw for sw in switches if device[:2]])` at least parses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use a conditional expression here. You want to *filter* switches, not produce different outcomes for each switch.

The condition per switch, expressed as one boolean test is:

```
device[2:4] == 'NB' or sw[:2] == device[:2]
```

so either the device is a notebook (and so *all* switches apply), or the country code must match. Put that in an `if` test at the end:

```
[sw for sw in switches if device[2:4] == 'NB' or sw[:2] == device[:2]]
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you